# specify order of fields in a FIX message using QuickFIX

Tags: c++, quickfix, fix-protocol

I know it sounds crazy, but my broker just dont accept the message i send and the reason is some fields(outside repeating groups) should be in front of some other fields.

I have solved a similar problem, specifying the order of fields in a repeating group by inheriting a class from group and passing a int array to specify the order

But it seems that for messages, I cant do that

Any suggests?

Comment: Is the broker asking for non-standard ordering?

Answer (score 2):

The FieldMap base class of Message accepts a message_order. Add a constructor to Message that allows a message_order to be specified to initialize the base class (see Message.h and Message.cpp). If you want this ability in the generated subclasses you will need to tweak the code generators accordingly. If you do this, I recommend donating the patches to the QuickFIX project.